# How to take a screenshot of table in HTML?

Tags: html, screenshot

I have a large table and my screen is not big enough to take 1 screenshot of it so I was wondering if there is any way I can take a screenshot of the whole table at once?

Comment: Does it need to be full size?  You could zoom out a bit so it fits width-wise...

Comment: It has to show the table and all its elements in a way which people can read. What do you mean by full size?

Comment: Your web browser is capable of zooming out and making the font smaller.  This is one way to make the table fit.

Comment: Yes, but it becomes to small and unable to read.. I was wondering if there is an alternative way to do that.

Comment: Do you need a screenshot of the table or the data within the table, what format is your table in(html, java form, C# program, etc...)? Why can't you reference the table directly, why the screenshot?

Comment: I need screenshot of the table, and it's coded in HTML. The reason I need a screenshot of it is because I'm using a Wordpress.com blog and I've created a Page, which becomes too big if I keep making tables over and over, I have a table for each month, with 30 rows for every day, so I want to make a screenshot of each table after a new month starts and display it as an image instead of code, so the Page when I edit it will be easier to handle.

Comment: Use https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/screengrab/ in firefox (note my updated answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options that I see are:

- Take lots of individual screenshots and overlap them in Paint.  This is fairly easy to do, just change the image width and height to support the extra shots.
- Get some virtual machine software, install a basic OS and window manager that allows for changing the size of the screen (e.g., Linux with Enlightenment), take the screenshot within the virtual OS and transfer it to your main system.
- Use the Firefox web browser with the [screengrab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/screengrab/) extension, as found in the answer to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/295938/how-to-take-a-screenshot-of-an-image-larger-than-the-screen).

Comment: I already thought of the first one, and tried it but I had some problems with connecting each picture. As for the second one, sounds interesting, but I'd prefer if there is an alternative way which doesn't take so much time and Internet bandwidth for only a screenshot.

Comment: A local virtual machine uses no internet bandwidth.  If you are taking lots of screenshots, this is the route I would suggest.

Comment: I only need one screenshot per month... and I am limited on bandwidth, so downloading the ISO for Linux, the VM files and all that takes a lot of bandwidth.

Comment: That is true.  What OS are you currently using?